# Updating Word Documents From a Master Template That is Periodically Updated

Tags: document-library

We provide legal services to IT firms using MS Word to create legal agreements including MSA's, SOWs, and DPA's.  We start with templates, customize them for each client, and then host and manage them in Azure. We need a solution that will allow us to push changes to the master templates to all customers whose documents were created with that template.  Ideally the proposed changes would show up as redlines in each of the clients documents.  Can you help?